# grid.py and gridregression.py: invalid syntax error in Python

Tags: python, grid, svm, libsvm

I am trying to do epsilon-Support Vector Regression.

In this page http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/, I was given grid.py for classification and gridregression.py for regression for optimal parameter selection.

I downloaded and set up Python 2.7. I put these two ".py" files to the directory of Python which is `C:\Python27`. I started IDLE (Python GUI) and wrote the code `python grid.py heart_scale`, which you can find this code in README file of Libsvm package. However, I got "invalid syntax" error. Thus, I changed "python" to "Python27" (which is the name of the directory). However, I still got the same error. I looked it up online and did not come across with a solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: The OP entered `python grid.py heart_scale` into IDLE.. think about that for a second. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's what I get for reading too quickly. Yep, don't need a traceback for this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `python grid.py heart_scale` is not Python code itself, so IDLE will tell you it's a syntax error.

Run it on the `cmd` console instead. Make sure you are in the correct directory first, or use the full path:

```
cd C:\Python27
python grid.py heart_scale
```

or

```
python C:\Python27\grid.py heart_scale
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am grateful for your precious help. I apologize for this silly question because I am not familiar with Python environment and I am trying to learn it from the beginning.